# Error in Overleaf do not have right line number

Tags: errors, overleaf, line-numbering

Here is always some errors in the overleaf, but the line is not the right one. Where is the right line, and what exactly is the problem? I do not get it, since the document compiles the right way.What should I do?

[image]

Comment: the error is reporting errors detected on line 133 of `subfigure.sty`

Comment: Where should this be? and why do you know it is 133, I do not find this, and line 133 is emty

Comment: you do not need to go to that line. somewhere in code you have not shown you have defined a counter `subfigure` so the `subfigure` package breaks as the command is already defined. It happens to detect this in line 133 of its code but that is not very relevant to anyone.

Comment: If you want help with an error message it is always best to provide a small complete test document that generates the error and show the error as tex, copied from the log, not as a screenshot.

Comment: yes, but my aim is to know where I could find out where the error is. So if there are lines and this is not useful, why it shows the lines anyways? I do not understand the errorsetting of overleaf. As long as the document shows anything I want, it is okay to me.

Comment: I added some text to my answer but the screenshot you show, shows you the full path to the file,  the error message and the line on the file. That is all the information tex has. It knows at that point that you have an error it can not know where you have previously defined the counter (and nor do we as you have shown no code)

Comment: sorry 113 not 133 it is hard to debug an image, which is why you should show the error message as text, and supply an example

Answer (score 5):

The error is reporting errors detected on line 113 of `subfigure.sty` which is where the package defines its `subfigure` counter that you have somehow already defined.

The log (and the error summary shown by overleaf) show you the error context

```
/usr/local/texlive/2020latex/texmf-dist/tex/latex/subfigure/subfigure.sty line 113

! LaTeX Error: Command \c@subfigure already defined.

l.113 \newcounter{subfigure}
```

But the fix is not at that point: you should fix your document not to define `subfigure` before loading the `subfigure` package.